# Stored Procedure does not return data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure. It is very simple

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPU_IsoSearch] 

@searchby varchar(4),
@userinput varchar(25)

AS
IF(@userinput IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  if(@searchby = 'fname')
     BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     SELECT CustID, CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustCity, CustEmail 
     FROM Customers where CustFirstName like '%' + @userinput + '%'
     ORDER BY CustFirstName
  END
END
```

Then, I'm executing it:

```
exec spu_isoSearch 'fname','de'
```

And it does not return anything, just a message "Command(s) completed successfully."

But if I just write:

```
select * from Customers where CustFirstName like '%de%'
```

I will get the data.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter 'searchby' is varchar(4), try changing to varchar(5) or the appropriate length

Since it is declared as varchar(4), your if statement compares 'fnam' to 'fname', and since those are not equal, the select statement does not execute

Comment: Thank's a lot. Did  not even look in there

Answer (score 1):

As Ghost(User) has mentioned the parameter length and on a side note your procedure can be cleaned up a bit more something like this..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPU_IsoSearch] 
@searchby varchar(5),    --<-- As pointed out by OP "Ghost"
@userinput varchar(25)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF(@searchby = 'fname' AND @userinput IS NOT NULL) 
   BEGIN 
     SELECT CustID, CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustCity, CustEmail 
     FROM Customers where CustFirstName like '%' + @userinput + '%'
     ORDER BY CustFirstName
   END
END
```

Comment: They are checking if userinput is null, not searchby

Comment: Thank's a lot It helped. Did not even look there